# PHP endless loop, why?

Tags: php, loops

Here is my code. I don't understand why am I in endless loop.
I think $check has to stop the loop when I make unique random values for my array.

```
    <?php

        $foo["blue"] = 0;
        $foo["black"] = 0;
        $foo["red"] = 0;
        $foo["white"] = 0;

        $check;
        do
        {
            foreach($foo as &$val)
            {
                $val = rand(1,6);
            }

            $foo = array_unique($foo);
            $check = count($foo);

        }
        while($check != 4);

        echo '............................ <br>';
        foreach($foo as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br>';
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Try putting `print_r($foo);` in the `do-while` loop to see what the values are.

Comment: @ishegg That's OK, it's how you update the current array element in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$foo = array_unique($foo)`. If, after the first iteration, the array has  duplicated values, then that line will make `$foo` an array of three or less elements, and thus `$check` will always be different than 4, thus the loop will be infinite.

The only way the loop will stop is if you get four different random values after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't do it in a loop with such low entropy as it could take all day to finally match a random set.

A better way would be to generate a range and randomise that, then loop over your array and set the value.

```
<?php
$rand = range(1, 6);
shuffle($rand);

$foo["blue"] = 0;
$foo["black"] = 0;
$foo["red"] = 0;
$foo["white"] = 0;

$i=0;
foreach ($foo as $key => $value) {
    $foo[$key] = $rand[$i];
    $i++;
}

print_r($foo);
/*Array
(
    [blue] => 1
    [black] => 3
    [red] => 2
    [white] => 5
)
*/
```

https://3v4l.org/4hPku

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first time through the loop there are some duplicates, so `array_unique()` reduces the array from 4 elements to 1, 2, or 3. The `foreach` loop can never make the array bigger again, because it's only looping over the elements that currently exist in the array. So once the array shrinks, it will never grow back to 4 elements, and `$check != 4` will always be true.

You should get the original keys of the array and use that.

```
<?php

    $foo["blue"] = 0;
    $foo["black"] = 0;
    $foo["red"] = 0;
    $foo["white"] = 0;
    $keys = array_keys($foo);

    $check;
    do
    {
        foreach($keys as $i)
        {
            $foo[$i] = rand(1,6);
        }

        $foo = array_unique($foo);
        $check = count($foo);

    }
    while($check != 4);

    echo '............................ <br>';
    foreach($foo as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo $key . ' ' . $value . '<br>';
    }

?>
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/8eE3zm)